# Solving a recurrence in which $n$ decreases by $\sqrt{2n}$

Tags: recurrence-relation, master-theorem

I'm trying to solve the recurrence
$T(n)= 2T(n-\log f(n))+ f(n)$, where $f(n) = 2^{\sqrt{2n}}$,
using the master theorem. Which case applies here?

Comment: Note that $\log f(n) = \sqrt{2n}$.

Comment: Your recurrence matches no case of the master theorem, which deals with a different kind of recurrence. The master theorem solves many recurrences which occur in practice, but not all of them.

Comment: The solution is most probably $T(n) = 2^{\Theta(\sqrt n)}$. I'm not sure what the hidden constant is.